# \align environment clipping off page

Tags: pdftex, align, rendering

When I compile my LaTeX with latexmk, my align environments start so far to the left that they clip off of the page and my enumeration labels clip into my theorem labels (see screenshots below).
[image: 1][image: 2]

Here is the LaTeX I am trying to compile (I apologize for all the custom commands):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
%----------Packages----------
\usepackage{verbatim}  %%includes comment environment
\usepackage{fullpage}  %%smaller margins
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{physics} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[mathcal]{eucal} % changes meaning of \mathcal
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\usepackage{mathrsfs}  
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{listings}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{todonotes} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%----------Commands----------
%%penalizes orphans
\clubpenalty=9999 \widowpenalty=9999

\newcommand{\li}{\lim\limits}
\newcommand{\unif}{\rightrightarrows}
\newcommand{\pM}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}  
\newcommand{\diff}{\D{x}}
\newcommand{\ox}{\otimes}  
\newcommand{\x}{\times}  
\newcommand{\ceq}{\coloneqq}
\newcommand{\T}{\top} 
\newcommand{\too}{\rightarrow}
\renewcommand{\l}{\ell} 
\renewcommand{\-}{\overline}
\renewcommand{\O}{\emptyset}
\renewcommand{\wd}{\wedge}

\providecommand{\ar}{\rightarrow} 
\providecommand{\arr}{\longrightarrow}

\renewcommand{\_}[1]{\underline{ #1 }}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ext}{ext} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\osc}{osc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}
\DeclareMathOperator{\intr}{int} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\grd}{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\inv}{Inv}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\inn}{\langle}{\rangle}

%----------Theorems----------

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma} 
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition} 
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{nondefinition}[theorem]{Non-Definition}
\newtheorem*{exercise}{Exercise} 
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{warning}[theorem]{Warning}

\numberwithin{equation}{subsection} 
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

%----------Title-------------

\title{Document 1}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{exercise}[5.33]
   \begin{proof}
       Let $T(A,B)=AB$ for $A,B\in \mathcal{M}(n\x n)$. Let $M\in G$. Then,
       \[
           T(\id, \inv)(X)=XX^{-1}=I.
       \]
       Thus, $(DT(\id,\inv)_{A}(X))=(D I)_{A}=0$.
       Since matrix multiplication is bilinear, by the Leibniz rule,
       \begin{align*}
           0=(DT(\id,\inv))_{A}(X)
           &=T((D\id)_{A}(X),\inv(A))+T(\id(A),(D\id)_{A}(X)) \\
           &=\id(X)A^{-1}+A\id(X) \\ 
           &\implies -XM^{-1}=M(D\inv)_{M}(X) \\
           &\implies -M^{-1}XM^{-1}=(D\inv)_{M}(X),
       \end{align*}
       as desired.
   \end{proof} 
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[IV]
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item
    \end{enumerate} 
    \end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Since it is also likely relevant, I am compiling with latexmk and using texlive 2023 on MacOS Sonoma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***NEVER*** do `\renewcommand` for a command you don't know about.

In your case, the culprit is

```
\renewcommand{\wd}{\wedge}
```

that clobbers a very important primitive of TeX.

Comment: Avoid also redefining `\l` and `\-`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! Serves me right for inheriting a template from someone without reading it carefully first.

Comment: @Otto It was quite an interesting puzzle, until I noticed the apparently innocuous `\renewcommand`. It would be interesting to understand why it doesn't throw errors with that input; it does with other constructions, though.

Comment: @Otto `\wd\wedge` is the width of box 8798 so would have been an error in classic tex but is usualy 0pt in etex unless you have allocated a lot of boxes